# hover при загрузке страницы, а не при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть ли элемент в css, наподобие `hover`, только чтобы эффект начинался сразу при открытии страницы, а не при наведении на элемент?

Comment: не ясно что требуется , какая задача ?

Comment: Это анимация в css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такого эффекта добиваются при помощи [CSS-анимаций](http://css.yoksel.ru/css-animation/).

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: scaleCircle 5s forwards;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}

@keyframes scaleCircle {
  to {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=circle></div>
```

Comment: это я понял, но мне нужно использовать и анимацию и transition одновременно, возможно такое сделать?

Потому как когда в анимации я меняю фоновый цвет, он меняется резко, а нужно постепенно

Comment: в анимации вы указываете ее длительность, потому там не может быть "резко". в приведенном примере размер увеличивается плавно ведь.

Comment: @S1lllver, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы